# Route packets for specific domain to another server

Tags: networking, routing, port-forwarding, domain

I have 2 servers on my network but I am behind a nat and I need to access port 80 on both.I port forwarded port 80 to server1 but server2 also needs that port.Is there any way I can route internet packets to server2 from server1 for specific domains?
For example to have server1.net on server1 and server2.com on server2 both listening to port 80 on the outside?

Comment: Since we’re talking about port 80, is this HTTP? Because what you want isn’t possible just with TCP/IP.

Comment: But isn't there any way I can see if the packets are coming on a specific domain like in apache and redirect it to another ip?

Comment: TCP and IP are not concerned with domains. HTTP (among others) is, because requests have the `Host` header. That’s why I’m asking: Is this HTTP? What router (make/model/OS) do you have?

Comment: I have a tplink tl-wr841

Comment: It doesn't answer the question as specified, but it sounds like what you really want is an additional "primary" web server acting as a [reverse proxy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy).

Comment: @Aleksss the serveres, are they both webservers? This is crucial information that has been asked by Daniel B twice, and both times you did not answer the question. If they are indeed webservers, then one webserver can direct the traffic to another server. If so, we would need to know what service or OS you are using as webserver. Windows with IIS? Linux with Apache? etc...

Comment: Yes they are webservers with ssl too.One has Ubuntu 16.04 server x64 and the other one is a raspberry pi with raspbian stretch.

Comment: SSL? On port 80? Please update your question with *all* details on what service is offered on port 80. Please describe both servers separately.

Comment: I have ssl on port 443 and normal unencrypted on port 80.

Comment: I said only port 80 because I assume that the process is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need use port 80 on external access? If not, you can redirect like this:

> Internet - router port 81 - server1 Port 80
>
> Internet - router Port 82 - server2 Port 80

Comment: Outside I need to use the same port(port 80), inside I can use any port.